# Is "Date" data type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I read JavaScript book called "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide" and I see the following.
"The Date type represents dates and times and supports rudimentary date arithmetic."

There is no "Date" in the list of primitive and object types, why "Date" is considered as type if it's just an object and in JavaScript if I am correct it's not possible to create our own types.

Is **Date** considered type in JavaScript?

Comment: Date can't be accessed directly using Date keyword. ```Date()``` returns the date in string format. ```new Date()``` Returns date in Date type.

Comment: No, it's an object. A class, if you wish. Occasionally an object of class X is called "object of type X".

Comment: It's an object, but a special one loaded with methods and properties - and in googling the nature of the Date object, I met it's future (date pun not intended), Temporal - https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "Date Type", [ECMASCript Types](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-typeof-operator) are:

1. Undefined
2. Null
3. Boolean
4. String
5. Symbol
6. Number
7. BigInt
8. Object

Note that the value returned by [*typeof*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-typeof-operator) does not necessarily match the Type of the value, e.g.

1. `typeof null` returns "object"
2. `typeof someFun` returns "function", where *someFn* is a an object that implements an [internal call method](https://262.ecma-international.org/#table-additional-essential-internal-methods-of-function-objects) (i.e. is a function)

ECMAScript has a built–in *Date* object that is a function that can also be called as a constructor. So:

```
typeof Date
```

returns "function" even though it's an Object Type, whereas using the *typeof* operator on a *Date* instance:

```
typeof new Date()
```

returns "object", as it's also an Object Type. The term "Date object" is commonly used to refer to a Date instance, and "Date constructor" to refer to the built–in Date object/function/constructor.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate @aravind's point:

```js
console.log(typeof Date());
console.log(typeof new Date());
```

Comment: You should distinguish between ECMAScript [*Types*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-ecmascript-language-types) and the value returned by [*typeof*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-typeof-operator), e.g. there is no *function* Type, however `typeof function(){}` returns `"function"`. There is also a *Null* type but `typeof null` returns `"object"`.